# Regex Expression to extract UK postcodes from an address string (Hive SQL)

Tags: sql, regex, string, hive, expression

I'm looking for a bit of help and I hope someone can give me some advice. Anything would be greatly appreciated. I have this regex expression to capture UK postcodes, and I'm happy with it, and when using this expression in any one of the following regex expression testers, the expression works and highlights the postcodes within a full address string (https://regex101.com/ or https://rubular.com/) but not in Hive.

```
\b(([A-Z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Z][A-HJ-Y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Z][0-9][A-Z])|([A-Z][A-HJ-Y][0-9]?[A-Z])))) [0-9][A-Z]{2}\b
```

However, the issue I have in Hive SQL is that I have used:

```
select regexp_extract(column, [expression], 0) from table
```

The above statement returns all rows back as **empty** - why is this? I have also tried to use the below statement to no avail:

```
select column from table where column regexp '[expression]'
```

I would only get an '**OK**' return on the query with no data.

Any help would be amazing :)